# is it possible to use two conditional filters, without having to assign variable filter (fifa dataset)

Tags: python, pandas

For context, I am using a FIFA dataset. fourfive_skillers['nationality'] is a float. fourfive_skillers['skill_moves'] is int64.

```
fourfive_skillers[fourfive_skillers['nationality'] == 'Brazil']
```

The above conditional gives me players only from Brazil. What if I want to add a second conditional that only gives me players with 5 skill moves? (i.e. `fourfive_skillers[[fourfive_skillers['nationality'] == 'Brazil' & fourfive_skillers['skill_moves'] == 5]]`. I tried that and it doesn't work. I understand that I can just assign a new variable filter for Brazil then apply the second conditional filter, but I was just wondering if there's anyway way to avoid that.

(Important to note that fourfive_skillers is a sliced view of `df` filtering for only 4+ skillers).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put both logical conditions in parentheses:

```
fourfive_skillers[(fourfive_skillers['nationality'] == 'Brazil')
                  & (fourfive_skillers['skill_moves'] == 5)]
```

It is needed because the `&` operator has higher precedence than `==`.